# What is wrong with my .Htaccess file? I'm trying to redirect permanently my whole site to the index.htm file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This is giving me a 500 internal server error. Any suggestions? I have tried various examples but I think I'm missing something...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{request_uri}!^ /index\.htm
RewriteRule  ^(.*) /index\.htm [R=permanent,L]
```

It displays the homepage if I navigate there but anything that meets the conditions (all appart from index.htm gives the server 500)

EDIT: with the above code it now doesnt give any 500 errors but it doesnt redirect for any pages

Answer (score 1):

You're not redirecting to `/index.htm`, you're redirecting to `/` which is different as far as Apache is concerned.

Try: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.htm [R=permanent,L]`

Comment: please can you edit out the domain - i forgot :)

Comment: Incidently I tried that just before your post with the same issue :(

Comment: I'm using utf-8 as the .htaccess file type is that correct?

Comment: still doesn't redirect but displays the original (old) page

Comment: What about capitalising REQUEST_URI?  It might be case-sensitive, and in all the Apache documentation, those macros ARE IN CAPS (not shouting, just illustrating :-P )

Comment: tried that now too no luck

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite condition isn't split up well and your Not-StartWith is part of the previous parameter. :) You need a space after the `%{REQUEST_URL}` and before the `!^`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.htm$
RewriteRule  ^(.*) /index.htm [R=permanent,L]
```